# How to pass array pointer using PInvoke from C# to C library

Tags: c#, c, pointers, pinvoke, unsafe

I am writing a software in C# which needs to call a function from a C library that is provided as a dll. Inside this library, there exists a function called

`getData(uint16_t  *buffer, const uint16_t dataIndex)`

that populates the provided array `buffer` , which is of length 4096, with the data corresponding to the `dataIndex` .

In C#, I tried the following to call this function:

```
[DllImport(DllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static private extern int getData(ushort[] buffer, ushort dataIndex);

ushort[] buffer = new ushort[4096];
int response = getData(buffer, 1);
```

This comiles and runs, however buffer always contains only random values from 0 to 65535. I also tried adding `[In, Out]` to the DllImport statement, but it did not help either. Previously, I wrote some working C++ code to use this library but had to change the codebase to C# as I was forced to use a library that only exists for C#, so I know that the library works.

The function call in C++ looked like this:

```
uint16_t Buffer[4096];
uint Respose = getFrame(Buffer, 1);
```

My guess is that the type marshalling is somehow incorrect, but I don't know how to do it correctly. I looked into type marshalling in C#, but I could not find a solution to the problem.

How do I get the data using this library? Is there another option, maybe using an `IntPtr` or using `unsafe` and manually reading and translating the data behind that memory adress? How can I check whether the passed memory is actually being written to?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, but you might want a `[In, Out]` attribute, see [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-different-types-of-arrays).  If you already have working C++ code to call it it you could just convert it to a C++/CLI project.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible C code? Passing in an output buffer without a length argument looks incorrect.

Comment: What is your C code doing exactly with the passed in buffer? You can try to declare it like this `static private extern int getData([In, Out] ushort[] buffer, ushort dataIndex);` PS: Charset is useless here, there's no char/string involved

Comment: @JonasH I already tried that, I did not work either. Also, I am forced to use a C# library, so conversion is not possible.

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't know exactly what the C code does, I am just given a compiled C dll. I know that it assigns values to data like so: `buffer[pixelOffset + indexOfPixelInPacket] = pixel`

Comment: If you don't fully know what the code does, you cannot fully define the signature in .NET properly. It's not only a matter of defining the list and types of arguments but also how the code behaves with these. Have you tried [In, Out]

Comment: @SimonMourier I will try to reach out to the developer to get hold of the source code. I have tried `[In, Out]` without success.

Comment: @Iridium There is no such thing as a c# library. Once it has been compiled it does not matter if it was written in C#, F#, c++/cli, etc. It all becomes CIL. But the typical usage of c++/cli is as an intermediate layer between c# and native c++, i.e. just use two projects/libraries.

Comment: @JonasH I tried using C++/CLI for that library and ran into so many issues as the only supported language is C# that I decided to switch to C#. It's the Beckhoff TwinCat ADS library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was: I was using the provided library wrong. As there was no documentation, I reached out to the developer and we were able to resolve it. The array was transferred and marshalled correctly all the time, the issue was at another function call.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an unsafe context (very often the simplest way to interop with native code), you can used a `fixed` pointer to the first element of the array, so that the GC won't move it around.

```
      ushort[] buffer = new ushort[4096];
      int response = 0;
      unsafe {
        fixed (ushort *pbuff = buffer) {
          response = getData(pbuff, 1);
        }
      }
```